# Remote System Service Restart

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to restart a service on a remote system?  Is it possible to start a service based on a script output?  Like, if the status of the service returns a "Stopped" status, to do something like the below pseudo-code...

```
if {service-status = Stopped | Get-Service -Name ServiceName | Start-Service}
```

Here's the example of my current code if any of this makes sense:

```
# Display status of Sophos Services
$Computer1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the computer name to check Sophos Services'
Get-Service -DisplayName sop* -ComputerName $Computer1

 # Service Stop
 $Service1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the service needed to be restarted'
 Echo "Stopping service"
 Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
 Get-Service -Name $Service1 -ComputerName $Computer1 | Stop-Service

 # Service Stop   
 Echo "Starting service"
 Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
 Get-Service -Name $Service1 -ComputerName $Computer1 | Start-Service
```

It would be nice to make this a little more automated of a process.
Hope this makes sense.

Thanx...

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot pipe a remote service object to `Stop-Service` or `Start-Service`. You will have to use a script block with the parameter -ComputerName to remotely stop or start a service. Please re-review the help for both cmdlets - they don't have a -ComputerName parameter. [Start-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-service?view=powershell-6), [Stop-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the `Restart-Service` cmdlet with Powershell Remoting (over WinRM) by using `Invoke-Command`. Note that while you *can* use the pipeline to get a service with `Get-Service` and pipe it to `Stop-Service`, `Start-Service`, or `Restart-Service`, that isn't really necessary here, and you can't directly invoke them on remote servers anyways:

```
$Computer1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the computer name to check Sophos Services'

$Service1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the service needed to be restarted'
Write-Output "Restarting service ${Service1} on ${Computer1}"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"

# Restart the service on the remote computer
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer1 -ArgumentList @{ Service1 = $Service1 } -ScriptBlock {
    Restart-Service -Name $args.Service1 -Force
}
```

### Let's break down `Invoke-Command`

`-ComputerName` - The name of the computer/server to run the command on. By default, your user account must either be in the `Administrators` or `Remote Management Users` group on the server you wish to connect to. You can specify an alternate credential with the `-Credential` argument if necessary. As an added bonus, you can pass in an array of computers to run the same `ScriptBlock` on in one go.

`-ArgumentList` - An array of arguments to pass to the script. The `ScriptBlock` won't be able to resolve your local variables when it's running on the remote machine. Normally you access each variable as `$args[0]`, `$args[1]`, and so on in the order the variables are passed in. I like to use a trick which is to pass in a hashmap of named arguments so you can access them in a more readable fasion, like how I use `$args.Service1` in the `ScriptBlock` below.

`-ScriptBlock` - This is the remote code you are going to execute, best placed in a `ScriptBlock` object which is represented by code between two curly-braces `{}`. In this case, we are calling `Restart-Service` on the remote computer.

### About the `Restart-Service` Cmdlet

I mentioned before that your user needs to be at least in the `Remote Management Users` group on the remote server in order to connect using Powershell Remoting. While this is true, in most environments you need to be a member of the `Administrators` group on the same remote server in order to also manage services, which included starting and stopping them. So in order for this to work end-to-end, you will need to be an administrator on the remote box you wish to restart the service on.

Comment: Bender... thank you for this and the great explanation.  I greatly appreciate the response and time given.

Question: When you say "_your user needs to be at least in the Remote Management Users group_", do you mean the **user** running the script or the user on the machine or the user who the script is running against?

Comment: I mean that the user you are running `Invoke-Command` as (by default, it will be the user you opened Powershell or ran the script as unless you specify a `-Credential`) must be in either the `Administrators` or `Remote Management Users` group on the box you are attempting to connect to. If you aren't on a domain, you will need to create a local user on the remote server, add it to one of those groups, and specify the `-Credential` parameter for that user when calling `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 2):

A more "Powershell way" of achieving what you asked for:

```
    function Restart-RemoteService {
    [CMDLETBINDING()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String] $ServiceName,

        [String] $ComputerName = 'localhost'
    )

    BEGIN {} #BEGIN

    PROCESS {

        $params = @{
            'Name'         = $ServiceName
            'ComputerName' = $ComputerName
        }

        Write-Verbose "Testing status of service"
        $Status = Get-Service @params

        if ($status.Status -eq 'Running') {
            Write-Host "Service $ServiceName has already been running"
        }
        ELSE {
            Write-Host "Starting Service $SeviceName"
            Get-Service @params | Start-Service
        }


    } #PROCESS

    END {} #END

} #function
```

The function will:

Expect two parameters:

ServiceName, which is mandatory therefore it will prompt you for it if not provided

ComputerName, computer on which you'd like to start the service. It defaults to localhost if no value is provided.

Then we're parsing these parameters to check the status of service - if it's running then nothing is being done, if anything else then the service will be started.

You'd like to paste this code into Powershell window and run it, or some code editor like VS Code - so that the function gets loaded to the memory.

The you run it by calling it's name:

```
Restart-RemoteService
```

Or you can pass some parameters like:

```
Restart-RemoteService -ServiceName bits -ComputerName den-dc1.company.pri -Verbose
```

Comment: This won't work as `Start-Service`, `Stop-Service`, and `Restart-Service` don't support the `-ComputerName` switch (which is perplexing as `Get-Service` does). You will need to `Invoke-Command` as evidenced in my answer to manage a remote service. Also, OP wants to restart a service, your script only starts it if it is not running.